# Where do you park a Star Destroyer at the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars

The Death Star is a huge space station, literally the size of a moon. Now I know you can park TIE fighters and shuttles and even craft as big as the Millennium Falcon inside of the station. But when you see this photo:

[image: Death Star 1 and a star destroyer]

Where exactly do you park a Star Destroyer at the Death Star? In the first episodes of the series, we've seen that the older version of star destroyers could actually land on the surface of a planet. While I'm certain that this newer version doesn't normally do that, would the Death Star actually have a landing bay for a vehicle this size?

Once again, where do you park a Star Destroyer once it's at the Death Star?

Comment: The photo's a tad misleading. The Star Destroyer is pretty far away from the Death Star; a side-by-side comparison would show that the Star Destroyer is tiny in comparison. I'm still not sure if large enough landing bays exist.

Comment: Totally know that's just a photo with the ship approaching. But those vessels are quite large. So what do they do them. Do they orbit the station, do they dock the ship, can they pull them inside like a station can in Star Trek? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @Chris: What would be the point of docking a Star Destroyer inside the Death Star?  Routine personnel travel is handled by shuttles and small craft, as is material transport, and routine maintenance is handled by the Star Destroyer's onboard repair staff.  Literally everything that smaller craft need to land/dock to deal with is a solved problem for capital ships (like Mon Cal cruisers and Star Destroyers).

Comment: The way I see that photo, I assume perspective such that the distance from the "camera" to the star destroyer is much less than the distance from the star destroyer to the death star. There is not enough information in the image to infer much beyond that. The slight fuzziness of the death star's surface detail and difference in lighting (star destroyer is well lit but overlaps the shadowed portion of the death star) leads me to infer likely relative distances such that the death star must be vastly larger than the star destroyer.

Comment: [jeff Russell's Starship Dimensions site](http://www.merzo.net/) has all the relative sizes you need for comparison. It looks to me like there would be no problem docking even a Super Star Destroyer inside a Death Star.

Comment: Just to fully clarify the Star Destroyer/Death Star relative sizes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS12p0Zqlt0

Comment: I think it depends also on which canon you are wanting answers for. For example: http://www.theforce.net/swtc/ds/hangars.html mentions a few game and tv blue prints that existed. And one thing in legends canon seemingly also mentioned complete star destroyer dry docks on the DS-1

Comment: Why do you have to "park" them at all?

Comment: @PlasmaHH my thoughts exactly. Or, why park them on the Death Star and not, say, a planet? That's like asking where you park a destroyer in an aircraft carrier.

Comment: You don't park a Star Destroyer in the Death Star, because otherwise Vader and The Emperor would have.  Recall in RotJ both Vader and The Emperor take shuttles to the Death Star 2. Those two have so much hubris, if they could have parked their Star Destroyer inside the Death Star instead of shuttling over they would have.  (I'll rebut this myself: it could have been because the docking bays on the DS2 were incomplete).

Comment: There's a Star Destroyer parking lot on levels 72043-73192, radials 92 through 104. Full disembarkation gantry support is provided in a partial G environment; there's a fully-equipped drydock with micro-droid-swarm technology for maintenance, repair, and rebuild needs; and you can have your ship washed, waxed, and detailed while-you-wait - and all at prices we're sure all Star Captains will find affordable! Just contact Central Control and ask for a tractor beam to pull you in.

Comment: The Star Wars Technical Manual has photos of the interior of a hangar bay with a TIE Fighter inside. It does not, however, mention whether or not there are any other larger hangar bays anywhere. The largest we see on screen is the one where Vader lands.

Comment: Considering the sheer mass of a Star Destroyer, and given momentum = mass*velocity, even an ISD moving at relatively low speeds could inflict catastrophic damage on the Death Star after a botched parking job. I wouldn't want an ISD anywhere near the Death Star (and vice versa) if I were in charge of Imperial Traffic Control.

Comment: Where do you park it? Preferably not in its path.

Comment: Parking lot on the other side? I am guessing they go in the bus/truck/destroyer section.

Comment: Just to fully clarify the Star Destroyer/Death Star relative sizes, with a link that works now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMiKyfd6hA0

Comment: Its worth linking this question here as its related *and* it has an excellent answer based on footage from Rogue One which shows a Star Destroyer docked with the Death Star: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122641/what-is-the-largest-size-vessel-the-death-star-could-accommodate-inside-any-hang?rq=1

Answer (score 78, accepted):

First, I find it hard to believe that those are scaled similarly.  The Imperial Star Destroyers (both the first and second class) are 1,600 meters long.  Essentially, they are *about* a mile long.  You could run from one end to the other in less than 10 minutes.

The Death Star was the size of a small moon.  The first Death Star was a rough sphere **120 kilometers** in diameter.  In other words, a Star Destroyer's length was 1.3% of the Death Star's diameter.  A docking bay capable of holding a Star Destroyer would need to be enormous.  Let's assume the Star Destroyer is a rectangular block 1600 meters long, 800 meters wide, and 800 meters high (which it isn't, it is significantly smaller than that) and that a docking bay needs to hold two of those with sufficient space for clearance and maintenance hardware.  Let's say this results in a bay that is 1800 meters long, 2400 meters wide, and 1000 meters high. That is a volume of 4,320,000,000 cubic meters (4.32 cubic kilometers).

That sounds HUGE, right?  It really isn't, compared to the internal volume of the Death Star. The Death Star has an 60,000 meter (60km) radius.  Plugging that into the calculations for the volume of a sphere, we find that it has a volume of 904,779 cubic kilometers.

That's means the theoretical bay would be less than 0.0005% of the internal volume of the Death Star.

So you can see, there could be **LOTS** of places they could put a docking bay for a Star Destroyer.

---

That said, there's no real need for them to have a docking bay for ships that size.

The purposes of docking bays is to allow maintenance, restocking of provisions/fuel, personnel movement, etc for small craft.  You park the *Millennium Falcon*, Chewie can climb up on top and mess about with hardware, you can attach feeder hoses to restock the water reserves, reclaim waste, refill consumables, etc.  People can walk onboard or leave.  All of this is needed with small ships, where space is as a premium.

Star Destroyers don't need to dock to accomplish this.  All of their routine maintenance is done without docking.  They were designed such that anything they can repair out of onboard capabilities can be done without needing to dock.  They have personnel who are trained to work EVA in those rare cases where external repairs are needed, and they have machine shops and engineers who can produce most of the parts they could need.

Refueling is not something that has been addressed.  We know (according to Wookieepedia) that the ships are powered by an 'I-a2b solar ionization reactor', which is referred to as seeming like a miniature sun.  This reactor uses fully half of the volume of the ship, and the fuel it consumes is unknown.  The Imperial Star Destroyer is listed as carrying 'consumables' for 2 years for its standard crew complement ([according to a rulebook published in 2014 for a licensed game](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Age_of_Rebellion_Core_Rulebook)).  Given that, we can assume that the ship was expected to not need to take on consumables for about a year at a time.  It would be reasonable to assume that it refueled when it restocked.

Star Destroyers that aren't in need of severe maintenance would find it easy to orbit the Death Star (as it could any moon-sized object).  Those which did need serious maintenance would likely have been sent to a dedicated repair facility, such as Kuat Drive yards (where many were constructed).

---

**TL;DR**: Your picture is *way* off scale, the Death Star is easily big enough to have docking bays big enough for Star Destroyers to land within, but it's unlikely that anyone would build them in because why would they need to land Star Destroyers within the Death Star?

Comment: Also, I don't think the picture is off scale, it's just that we see a Star Destroyer _approaching_ the Death Star, but it's still a long way off. And also, how did that surplus r end up in my other comment?

Comment: Even if you did want to dock a Star Destroyer with the Death Star, you could do it in any number of ways.  "Nose-in" docking, landing on the surface, low orbits etc...

Comment: This ship is too big! If I walk, the movie will be over!

Comment: @SQB: Math corrected to account for DS1's correct radius, as well as a minor calculation error I made.

Comment: @SQB I think the extra 'r' is because there were only two Death Stars, and the both got destroyed. So clearly, the Empire didn't have enough of them. There was a dearth of Death Stars.

Comment: While I agree the Death Star probably didn't have facilities for building/repairing capital ships (since its primary purpose was to blow things up and terrify people), one wonders what advantages a mobile ship yard with a Death Star-like design would have.

Comment: @jpmc26: I don't think there's really a lot of advantages.  Star Wars already has mobile repair ships that can be used to repair ships to the point where they can make it to a shipyard.  There's not much advantage to a hyper-capable mobile yard, as ships under construction would be a difficult thing to haul through hyper, and the added mass would make hyper both slow and power-intensive.

Comment: The mass/speed/power problems have already been more or less solved; otherwise, the Death Star would have been immobile. I was trying to think if there would be any tactical advantage to moving a ship yard around or being able to. I was specifically considering if it would be more difficult to attack/destroy/capture, since it wouldn't be bound to a single location like the known major ship yards. Maybe I'm just going off the deep end, though.

Answer (score 82):

[image: A Super Star Destroyer crashing into the Death Star]

As you can see, even a Super Star Destroyer is much smaller than the Death Star.

Of course, this was the second Death Star, which was just a tad bigger than the first one — a diameter of 160 kilometres vs 120 kilometres.

---

Your picture shows a Star Destroyer approaching the Death Star, but it seems to be still a long way off, which is why it looks relatively big, compared to the Death Star.

Comment: This is a very liberal interpretation of the word "Park".

Comment: That was actually the Death Star 2 that the Executor crashed in. the Death Star 2 was over 5X larger than the Death Star 1.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs How do you derive from an increase in diameter from 120km to 160km to a factor of 5?? It was one third larger, that's it.

Comment: @BMWurm Outdated sources that make me believe the DS1 was 160 KM and the Death Star 2 was 900 KM big.

Comment: @BMWurm, just being pedantic here, but when you increase the radius (or diameter) of a sphere by a factor of 33%, you increase the volume by a factor 137% (more than twice, but still not near 5 times)

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu You're right of course, I was just thinking about the diameter, but as it is a sphere you gain a lot more space - Saturday evenings are not the time for math apparently :P

Comment: Also, for reference - the Executor was 19,000 metres long. The Imperial-I class in episode IV was "only" 1,600 metres long - making a the Executor more than 12 times length of an Imperial-I

Comment: @Richard [Like a glove](http://cdn.gagbay.com/2013/01/like_a_glove-225694.jpg)

Comment: While this was worth posting purely for Richard's response, it *really* doesn't answer the question at all. It just says something about the OP's picture being misleading regarding size. -1, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jpmc26 I was utterly surprised by the massive amount of up votes this answer has gotten.

Comment: Actually the picture in your answer does not seem at scale. If the depicted ship is 19km long (as claimed by @HorusKol), the part of the Death Star at the left edge of the picture would be roughly 60km from impact. Now, since the radius of the Death Star is 80km, at 60km distance the curvature should be pronounced significantly. All I see in that picture is a flat expanse of techno-jumbo.

Comment: Lucas really messed up the scale factors in the scene shown in this post.  If you assume a 19km length for the Executor, based on the measurements of the curvature in this picture, the death star would have a diameter of about 11,300km; just a smidge smaller than the Earth.

Comment: I did my math wrong: 22,600km; about 2X bigger than the planet Earth.

Comment: Or, if we assume the Death Star in that image is really 160km in diameter, that would make the Executor only 134 meters long.

Comment: Bounty for setting up the funniest punchline on the site.

Answer (score 19):

The DS-1 Orbital Battle Station (also known as Death Star) did not have any specific docking bays for Star Destroyers. It had numerous docking bays for smaller ships, like TIE-class fighters and bombers, or landing shuttles, along its equator in a 1 km wide trench (source: Wookieepedia article on the Death Star).

They didn't need a special docking bay for larger ships, because nearly all Star Destroyers had their own docking bays, so they could simply shuttle over. Also, consider that a docking bay of that size would require a massive forcefield to keep the air in. (source: Original Trilogy footage).

In addition, the way physics work is that it would be very difficult for a Star Destroyer to stay airborne in the artificial gravity the Death Star has without inflicting massive structural damage to the docking bay. This is because, for the Star Destroyer to stay airborne, it would have to exert a force equal to its own mass on the floor. According to https://archives.swc-empire.com/a/index.php?title=Imperial_Star_Destroyer_I, an Imperial I Star Destroyer can weigh 6.4 million T. You would need a VERY strong docking bay floor to support that kind of weight.

However, the DS-1 does have a number of dry docks. I am not sure how canon these are, since this whole new Canon/Legends division has me confused, but here is an image from https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star

[image: Star Destroyer in docking bay]

Comment: This all sounds very plausible. That said, it also sounds like fan-theory. Can you back any of this up?

Comment: @Richard I shared some of my sources on this matter. I also removed the biggest speculation part about the technology.

Comment: Except that we see ships nearly as large parked on the ground at Coruscant. When you've got gravity-manipulation tech, the actual mass of an object is largely irrelevant.

Comment: You are getting your descriptions and therefore your units wrong.  Thrust(force) != mass.  The weight (force) of a Star Destroyer may be 6.4 megaTonnes x m/sec^2 but it's mass would only be 640 kiloTonnes.  Since the gravitational acceleration of DS would be <1/10 of Earth's, assume it weighs 640 kiloTonnes x m/sec^2 *or less* on DS.

Comment: @Jim2B I think Nate is assuming an earth-like artificial gravity in the landing bay, not the natural gravitation of the death star (which would be much lower, as the DS is not massive as a real moon).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Exactly. From what I could tell from ANH, the DS-1 has artificial gravity similar in strength to that of Earth. I couldn't find any official sources on how strong the gravity generator on the DS-1 is, though.

Comment: Also note depending on the DS density it ill have a gravity on it's own and is much more plausible to big starships to keep orbiting it and just shuttle between the ships and that "no moon"

Comment: Compared to the power it would take to ***shatter*** an Earth-sized rocky planet a force field (or magnetic containment field) to keep air in an enormous docking bay is nothing.

Comment: @jeff I'm not exactly talking about the power requirements. More about the size requirement.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: Size requirements are laughably tiny.  See my answer for the math.  Such an enormous bay would take up FAR less than one hundredth of one percent of the volume of the Death Star.

Comment: @Jeff Apparently, I just found a mention of a dry dock with Star Destroyers present on the Death Star. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 11):

The Death Star had [mooring towers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mooring_tower) for docking large spaceships like Star Destroyers.

[image: Mooring tower on the surface of the Death Star]

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Good find (+1)! I added an image to improve the answer (link-only answers are discouraged), but the addition of the image provides visual evidence here on SFF.SE.

Comment: You may wish to add a note that the referencing for this is from a non-canon source, namely an online promotional game called "Death Star Designer"

Comment: Isn't that tower in the picture the location of the Emperor's throne room? Definitely not a mooring tower.

Answer (score 3):

The movies never address the question, however the series background FAQ might. In the movies, we do however see multiple times shuttles landing on the death stars to transport resources, troopers and dignitaries (specifically Vader and Palpatine).

So i would say that it is far more likely that star destroyers do not dock and instead use shuttles to transport between the ships.

However as mentioned above, the death star would have adequate space for thousands of star destroyer docking bays, so it is not at all out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

From what I recall of the original “Star Wars” movie trilogy, Star Destroyers would only ever have been “parked” around the Death Star, not inside it, even though I suppose there would be plenty of room to park a whole fleet of them inside.

Answer (score 1):

First, as @SOB's picture points out, the Star Destroyers are still noticeably smaller than the Death Star, and so one *could* potentially fit inside.

Second, we can see that the Millenium Falcon manages it by a simple application of landing struts.

[image]

While a Star Destroyer could potentially have landing gears to do the same, [evidence is inconclusive at best](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/66266/20533) on whether or not they do - and leans towards 'they don't'.  However, 'older' models do in fact have landing struts, which were designed-on in the prequels that came out after ANH-ROJ.

They could also dock by hanging, which is how TIE fighters do it in some canon, but there's even less evidence to support this theory.

So while there are some ways in which a Star Destroyer could dock internally with the Death Star, none seem to be shown in any canon.

Comment: -1 for a speculative ("it's not difficult to imagine") answer. +1 for hand-drawn circles.

Comment: @KSmarts Speculative but based on real ship models.  I know this answer would be improved with something as simple as the design documents for the Star Destroyer (or fan-made ones, or lucas-made ones) but I don't know where those are.

Comment: -1 for failing the Square-Cube Law. Landing struts don't scale well.