# How big is the Death Star compared to the Executor

Tags: star-wars, death-star

We know the size of the Death Star (2nd one) to be 160 km in diameter, and the length of the Executor Super Star Destroyer to be 19 km.
In ROTJ we see the Executor smash into the Death Star, [image: [image in this post][1].]

This is obviously way off scale.

What should this scene actually look like?  Has anyone seen a scale-corrected version of this scene?

Comment: added the actual picture replacing the link, since your whole question is based off the picture. :D

Comment: it is interesting they chose to show it at the wrong scale here.  the point of what's happening in this Act is that the empire is gonna loose.  if the correct scale was shown, it would have emphasized the damage more... // more likely it was just an unimportant detail to them

Comment: @zipquincy More likely they just didn't want to bother with using a curved surface. Afterall this whole Death Star surface looks like a flat plane without any perceivable surface structure at all in this picture. That's probably just way easier to do, I guess.

Comment: they didnt want to break their actual death star.

Comment: The surface of the Death Star was a flat model which is why it appears to be flat (and out of scale). At the time, computer animation wasn't quite able to make a realistic surface to crash the Executor into. Here is a picture that shows one of the (huge) models they had to build. http://www.screenused.com/images/starwars/STAR_WARS_BONUS_DISC-7.jpg Note: this may not be the actual Death Star model, but it was very similar.

Comment: Where did the 19km figure come from, though?  I'd argue that the movie is the more canonical source, so it is whoever decided that Executors are 19km long that made the mistake.

Comment: oh lord, not another edit for Lucas to make

Comment: This question is no doubt inspired by the commentary at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82759/21871 , q.v..  ☺

Comment: Duh, this is all the correct scale and just lens distortion from a sithn hand shops crappy webcam.

Comment: On which grounds are you saying it's way off scale? Maybe, that's the answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The 19km figure comes from comparing the ILM models (both on screen and off) of the Executor and the other star destroyers.  Which is why the 160km figure of DS2 is ridiculous (and it's inconsistent with the ILM's spec docs for DS2 as well).

Comment: @Nick2253: off-screen doesn't count, IMO.  As for on-screen, I'd have to see specific screenshots to decide whether they were convincing or not.  It seems unlikely; for example, how do you know that (in-Universe) there aren't two types of spaceship that look the same except that one is bigger than the other?

Comment: @HarryJohnston If you don't count off-screen sources, then there's nothing to refute your statement about multiple, different sized but otherwise identical looking ships.  The 160km figure for the Death Star is completely from off screen sources.  You can trace screen-shots from human to Tantive IV escape pod, to Devastator bay, to Devastator, (extrapolate to generic Star Destroyer) to Executor to get the 19km size.  Given that, we know a lower bound on the DS2 diameter, from the movies alone, must be about 450,000x human size (about 900km)

Comment: A different question is "given the above picture, how big is the death star"?

Comment: @Yakk, I've done the math on that.  Depending on measuring error, it's either 22,600km in diameter, based on a perceived 1 pixel curvature, (twice as big as earth) or infinite.  Infinite is the proper answer since this scene was shot using a flat model for the death star and any curvature is an artifact of image resizing or lens imperfections.

Comment: Hmmm... follow-up question: How does the 160km number for DS2 hold up when looking at the pictures of DS2 orbiting Endor (e.g. during the Rebel briefing)? *Are* there canonical numbers for the size of Endor?

Comment: my sources suggest that the first death star had a radius of 160km (diameter = 320km) and the second death star was arguably bigger. the latest suggestion is 400km diameter (radius 200km) but long time it was told that it had 900km radius. but you are right: even with 900km that picture is off scale

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Darth Satan got it first and deserves the credit, but I couldn't resist doing this in Photoshop:

[image]

I took the picture in the question, found a frame from before it where the Executor hasn't hit the station yet so I could see how long the nose is, did a proportional resizing because the resolutions weren't the same, overlaid the full Executor on the crash frame so I could see the full size from stem to stern, measured that in pixels, adjusted it up for the rotatation of the angle of the ship against the pixel grid, to get:

250px Executor = 19km

Then I got a fairly large full Death Star II image and scaled it up proportionally:

DS2 = 160km

250/19 = x/160

x = 160 x 250 / 19 = 2105px

Then I rotated it 90 degrees to get the angle of crash more correct than it would be coming into the top of the Death Star (since during the battle, the main laser was aimed at the fleet battle. Also if it hit the top, it would have landed right next to where Luke, Vader, and the Emperor were, so they would have got quite a view and quite a shake.). Then I touched up the mixing of the images, such as fixing the black line between the explosion and the ship.

Comment: If obi wan shuddered when the alderon blew up a jillion light years away, why didn't a room full jedis on the death star flinch when all these people died?

Comment: @user973810 Allderan was peaceful.  The dark side doesn't care.  And Luke has bigger things on his mind at that moment.

Comment: @Zibbobz nah. The alderon thing literally knocked kenobi on his ass and he was nowhere nearby. You're just making wild rationalizations. But that's 90% of the purpose of this site.

Comment: @user973810 Might be good to ask that as a question on the site. I'm not sure why it's a comment to this answer to this question about the scale of things.

Comment: I got it first but yours is better.

Comment: @Dronz, Despite the truly awesome nature of Darth Satan's special effects skills, you get the accept for extra effort on the image. :)

Comment: Hmmm, if I wasn't so lazy I would script up an animated svg showing the Executor actually flying into the Death Star. Good thing I'm lazy :)

Comment: There's bound to be an opportunity for a comedy pie chart to answer this.

Comment: I have to say, the correctly scaled version makes the Death Star II look smaller and less daunting.

Comment: @jamesdlin Or alternatively, it makes the Executor seem huge and far more intimidating.

Comment: @jpmc26 I know that's what I'm supposed to think, but somehow that's just not my first impression when I look at it. =/

Comment: The problem is that the shot made the Executor seem tiny, and it exploded in a little *blip*. If the Executor were shown to scale to the perspective of that shot, it would be horrifyingly large.

Comment: Ya, before I rotated the Death Star II 90 degrees, it would have landed outside Palpatine's office, which would have made quite an impression. I think it could be a very impressive scene if it were zoomed it a lot.

Answer (score 76):

To scale it would have looked something like this:

[image]

Source: I drew a 160 pixel diameter circle and a 19 pixel long triangle in a paint program, then scaled them up 2x.

Comment: Fear my awesome special effects

Comment: -1 no hand-drawn circles

Comment: Impressive stuff. Which university do you teach graphics art at?

Comment: For all we know, this is the highest level in the game Asteroids.

Comment: @Richard - does the edit address your question?

Comment: @DVK - Very much so. LOL

Comment: @JackBNimble Time to brush up on my programming skills, because I intend to make that game. I may need Darth Satan's help with the graphics, though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an article which has sizes for both Death Stars.

There is some uncertainty on whether the Second Death Star was 160km wide or up to 900km.

Cannon purists seem to favor the larger size!

http://www.moseisleyspaceport.org/how-big-is-the-death-star/

Comment: Can you add the relevant sections of that linked article to your answer? The trouble with links is that they sometimes go out of data, and your answer becomes kind of useless if that ever happens. Having all the necessary information here mitigates that problem