# How big is the Executor, based only on film evidence

Tags: star-wars

This question is a spin-off of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82987/147).  Someone asked in the comments, How do we know the Executor is 19km long?

Based solely on canonical (film-only) evidence, how do we know this?

Comment: You should exclude the picture from the linked question from the allowed evidence.

Comment: Well, if you count actual models made for the movies into canonical evidence, that's how - the actual model was scaled to be 19km (actually, 11 miles). It was designed to be 11x the length of a star destroyer, and TESB and ROTJ were very good at their scaling, so there's no contradictory evidence.

Comment: Curtis Saxon has thoroughly documented the size and scale of different vehicles on his *Star Wars Technical Commentaries* pages.  They are well worth the read if you are really curious: http://www.theforce.net/swtc/ssd.html

Comment: That one cannot see the curvature of the Death Star when the Executor plows into it might be of some use to establish bounds on its size... though out-of-universe I have serious doubts the special effects folks took that into account.

Comment: I tried to work out something using the scale of Admiral Piett standing in front of the windows to estimate the height of the tower to estimate the length of the Executor, but couldn't find the right shots to go from tower height to tower depth.  I did work out the main hexagonal portion of the tower is about 50m high.

Answer (score 52):

Below is support for the 19km length of the Executor.

Bear with me, this is a long chain of evidence, but it is all taken directly from movie footage and nowhere else.

The following image is a screenshot from Episode IV taken the moment the Tantive IV fully enters the shadow of the docking bay on the Star Destroyer.  At this moment, we can then use this image to measure the size of the Tantive IV and the size of the docking bay.

[image: The Tantive IV framed by the entrance to the Star Destroyer's docking bay]

C-3PO can stand upright in the escape pod, and based on footage <s>from the surface of Tatooine</s> from inside the pod, the outside diameter of the escape pod is approximately 3 meters.

[image: C-3PO (sitting) and R2-D2 (standing) looking out the escape pod port]

C-3PO (sitting) and R2-D2 (standing) looking out the escape pod port.

Starting from this point, we get the total length of the Tantive IV as about 120-130 meters (122 in my measurements).  The docking bay in the Star Destroyer then measures 192 meters.

There are several other scenes where we can get a very clear picture of docking bay size vs total length of Star Destroyer.  My best measurements show the ship is 8.7 times longer than the docking bay, giving a Star Destroyer length of 1672 meters.  Just from screenshot measurements.

In ROTJ it is difficult to get precise measurements between a Star Destroyer and the Executor since you are never 100% sure that the two are in the same plane (field of depth).  What can be seen clearly is that the Executor is a **minimum** of 10 times the length of an ordinary Star Destroyer.  So, a minimum of 16.7km.  19km is absolutely plausible.

<s>Death Star size is harder to get based on screen footage only, but it is very definitely shown to be smaller than 300km.</s>  I currently have no direct evidence to support the previous statement.  (I'm definitely not the first one to follow this chain of image evidence.)

Comment: +1 It would also be great if you could add an image showing the approx 3m escape pod? How accurate is that? 3m-5m? or 3m +/- 1m?

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?

Comment: Yes, I did answer my own question:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer, though as with any interested knowledge seeker, I am also hoping someone provides either a viewpoint to refute mine, or more detailed supporting evidence.

Comment: That is NOT the SSD Executor, but the ISD Devestator. The Executor wasn't even built by that time and first appears in TESB (if we only take the films as evidence). The absolutely brilliant http://theforce.net/swtc/ssd.html#size gives the best and most exhaustive answer to the size question (and many other SW technical questions are discussed as well http://theforce.net/swtc/).

Comment: @BMWurm, As I stated in the text of the answer, the image shows the Tantive IV entering the docking bay of a star destroyer, not a super star destroyer.  Obviously it's not an image of the Executor.

Comment: @Stewbob You're right, of course, my mind just added the super in there because of the context of the question lol, oops. You might actually enjoy the SWTC site quite a lot, because Curtis Saxton uses basically the same method as you to reach the same conclusions. Careful though, one can get lost on his site :P

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: Interestingly enough the Super Star Destroyer was only 7km long in Xwing Alliance end to end.

Comment: Can anything be made from the scenes where fighters fly close to (and the one where one crashes into the bridge of) the _Executor_? Also, are there no useful shots in _The Empire Strikes Back_?

Comment: @Dronz - Yes, there are several scenes in ESB where we see Star Destroyers dwarfed by the *Executor*. See this website where the author uses ship length ratios from ESB to calculate the size of the *Executor*: http://www.theforce.net/swtc/ssd.html#ratio.