# Were Acclamator class landing craft still used by the Empire?

Tags: star-wars

During the Clone Wars, the *Acclamator*-class landing craft was a large landing transport that could carry a large army.  Were those crafts still used by the Empire after the Clone Wars?  The only landing crafts we see in the Galactic Civil war movies are the *Lambda* and *Sentinel* class shuttles. How did they bring a large army to a planet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never seen an *Acclamator* in use by the Empire in canon, and [Wookieepedia's canon article on the ship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Acclamator-class_assault_ship) indicates that it was not used by the Empire. This is likely because the *Venator*-class Star Destroyer started to replace it even before the Clone Wars ended. [It *was* used by the Empire in Legends sources](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Acclamator-class_assault_ship/Legends), such as [*Star Wars: Empire At War*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Empire_at_War).

---

> How did they bring a large army to a planet?

In canon, the Empire used the following ships of varying sizes to deploy troops:

- [*Sentinel*-class shuttle](http://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-sentinel-class-shuttle)
- [*Lambda*-class shuttle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lambda-class_T-4a_shuttle)
- [Imperial Dropship Transport](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Dropship_Transport)
- [Y-85 Titan dropship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Y-85_Titan_dropship/Canon) could deploy four AT-ATs and four AT-STs, which in turn could carry [40 troops per AT-AT](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Armored_Transport).
- [*Gozanti*-class cruiser](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gozanti-class_cruiser), capable of deploying TIE fighters, [AT-ATs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Gozanti_with_AT-ATs.png), troops, etc.
- [*Venator*-class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Venator) (before it was phased out of the Imperial Navy)
- [*Imperial*-class Star Destroyer](http://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-star-destroyer). Note that the Star Wars Databank says it can deploy assault units (troops):

  > Its belly hangar bay can launch TIE fighters, boarding craft, land assault units, hyperspace probes, or be used to hold captured craft.

  We see a Star Destroyer hovering over Jedha in *Rogue One* in order to acquire kyber crystals from the city:

  [image]

  Presumably it could be used to deploy troops in a similar manner, though [it's not clear if it can actually land](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66261/31936).

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Acclamator_II-class_assault_ship#cite_note-Wizards-3

Answer (score 0):

They instead used Imperial cargo ships which were modified Acclamators and still carried the same amount of clones except as stormtroopers (16,000) it only required a larger crew.

Comment: *Where* (and when) did they use them? What evidence can you offer to back this up?

Answer (score -2):

Some of the Venator-class Star Destroyers were sent to backwater planets in the outer rim
It could be assumed that the Acclamator would have the same fate as its larger brother.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back this up?